# Trying to get pygame to load an image. It worked before, but now all of a sudden it doesn't load the game anymore

Tags: python, image, pygame

This is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Bradley Kittle/Desktop/python_class/2nd_game/platform_KING.py", line 10, in <module>
    icon = pg.image.load('crown.png')
pygame.error: Couldn't open crown.png
```

Comment: Have you checked your 'crown.png' file manually to make sure it exists and hasn't been corrupted in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Just open your file manager and ensure that 'crown.png' in present in the same path. If that doesn't solve the issue, check if your required file is in the admin directory. If so, run your IDE as an administrator or just move the file to your user.

Thanks :)